# Can not resolve synmbol EnableWebSecurity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven, spring-security, аннотации

Добрый день.
В pom.xml лежит следующий список зависимостей:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...

    <!-- Add Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add Jstl Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</project>
```

Пишу конфигурацию для spring-security:

```
package ru.project.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("superadmin").password("superadmin").roles("SUPERADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/confidential/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", false);

    }
}
```

Но Idea не может найти ни аннотацию EnableWebSecurity, ни класс WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
В чем может быть проблема?

Вот результат выполнения mvn compile -X :

https://note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/fcf05f327dc9b6cf0296aac0501c8f07?page=1

Comment: а maven собирает проект без проблем?

Comment: При maven install: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: а maven скачал зависимости? вы можете их найти в локальном репозитории?

Comment: ну так может вы не вписали либу в которой находится WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter в pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зашел в pom.xml, нажал правую кнопку, в выпавшем меню выбрал maven -> Reimport и зависимости подключились.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в класс

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
```

Comment: Уже на слове security idea говорит, что не может распознать символ.

Comment: запустите `mvn compile -X` и добавьте результат выполнения в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил в текст вопроса результат

Comment: добавьте полный результат, а не кусок.

Comment: Прикрепил ссылку на весь вывод в консоли т.к. там 60 000 символов. Темы только 30 000 могут содержать.

Comment: вы запускали `mvn compile` с добавленными `import` или без?

Comment: Добавил четыре зависимости, которые вы указали и выполнил mvn compile -X. В итоге BUILD SUCCESS, а idea intelij до сих под не распознает зависимости.
https://note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/fcf05f327dc9b6cf0296aac0501c8f07?page=2

Comment: @ks_on_v обновите проект в ней.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: @ks_on_v Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Дак этот вопрос еще не закрыт и совет "обновить проект" касается этого вопроса.

Comment: Нажал Ctrl + T. Открылось окно "Update Project". Радиобатоны на "Branch" и "Using Stash". Далее ОК. И результат тотже.